# Is there an equivalent to CPP's line pragma in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Some tools generate latex. If there's a problem with the generated tex file, tools like pdflatex will point to the line in the generated file, not the source file (in whatever format it was). This is annoying if there are multiple files or if the tex file is large.

Is there an equivalent to CPP's line pragma (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) that would allow me to insert some information for pdflatex so that errors are reported as originating from a different line in a different file?

Comment: TeX already prints to the console which file it is busy processing, and if an error occurs, it'll be associated with that file, not the main file (assuming you're talking about nested files via `\input` or `\include`). Perhaps an example of input and the expected output would help here.

Comment: No, no. I'm talking about taking a different format and compiling to latex, and then compiling the tex to a pdf.

Comment: A concrete use case is [`lhs2TeX`](https://github.com/kosmikus/lhs2tex), which inserts a bunch of stuff and inlines all included sub-files into one big *.tex blob. It would be good to map lines in that blob back to the original .lhs file from whence they came